# Json карта возвращает nil

Tags: json, golang

я только начал изучать Go и решил сделать простой http запрос и вернуть json, но вот незадача, при запросе по адресу:
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 я получаю результат, но при запросе на адрес
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/ возвращается nil
Вопрос: почему так и как это исправить.
Код:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

    func main() {
    var dat map[string]interface{}
        resp, err := http.Get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()
    dec := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
        if dec.Decode(&dat) != nil {
            fmt.Println("error:", err)
        }
        fmt.Println(dat)
    }
```

Comment: Советую почитать https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go, по уму конечно надо данные закидывать в структуру.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том что вы берёте не один элемент JSON, а массив, поэтому надо объявлять не *var dat map[string]interface{}*, а массив *var dat []map[string]interface{}*, и потом проходить по массиву и получать данные.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    var dat []map[string]interface{}
    resp, err := http.Get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    dec := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    if dec.Decode(&dat) != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    for _, v := range dat {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", v)
    }

}
```

Comment: Благодарю, оказывается все было так просто. И за ссылку на блог тоже.